# select is not recognized as an internal or external command - jq

Tags: jq

I had downloaded jq and trying to get a hang of it on Windows.
I am able to run some basic queries in jq but when I am trying to use `select` with jq  I am getting the below mentioned message.

Below is the command which I am executing.

<s>`curl --basic -u admin:admin http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/mmc-console-3.7.3/api/deployments | jq .data[] | select(.name=="TestAccount").id`</s>

`curl --basic -u admin:admin http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/mmc-console-3.7.3/api/deployments | jq .data[] | select(.name==\"TestAccount\").id`

**Output**

`select is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I have jq in my path but not sure what I have to add in my path so that it can recognize `select as a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the JQ expression, e.g.:

```
curl --basic -u admin:admin http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/mmc-console-3.7.3/api/deployments | jq '.data[] | select(.name=="TestAccount").id'
```

when on Windows you'll need to use double quotes and escaped double quotes as in:

```
curl --basic -u admin:admin http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/mmc-console-3.7.3/api/deployments | jq ".data[] | select(.name==\"TestAccount\").id"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Now I am getting this.
`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.data[]
jq: 1 compile error
'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I am on windows so when I used double quote it worked. This is what it worked for me. Can you please edit the answer.
Thanks for your help. 
`curl --basic -u admin:admin http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/mmc-console-3.7.3/api/deployments | jq ".data[] | select(.name==\"TestAccount\").id"`

Comment: Thanks, the double quotes `"` are the only ones that worked for me on Windows in a bat file.